# Tridion Custom Pages URL is getting reset, where does Custom Page information stored in SDL Tridion?

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, custom-page

It has to point to the PROD URL of the custom page application, but resets to DEV URL of the same custom page. If they change it, that resets back to DEV. We have changed it 3 times and within few minutes during the process of using that application to upload with some Content, the URL got changed back to the DEV URL.

where does Custom page information stored in SDL Tridion?
Like it has some information under info tab Created by , Created time, Modified by & Modified time.
In one of the forums link we have seen below comment:
Custom pages are stored in CustomPages.xml from below path
%TRIDION_HOME%web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Preferences\
But we don't have specified file in CME server mentioned Path.

It would be great if you suggest any resolution.

Comment: I _think_ this is now stored in the database, but wouldn't be able to tell you where.

Comment: Hi @NunoLinhares, thanks for your swift response, entries Stored in the Database is from Sites 9 on-words, But at present the Customer is using SDL Web 8.6 version.

Comment: When you state "that application to upload with some Content" - what content is "that application" updating - and *how*? I'm wondering if your application is using something such as the Content Porter API and is inadvertently bringing in the content the pertains to the Custom Page URL?

Comment: Hi @Sarang Deshmukh, Could you please help on Mark Comment.

Comment: Hi, excel is provided as an input and the application create components present in the excel rows and create a page, add it to the page. Application is just using a normal core service to create the components and pages based on the configuration and inputs taken from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. Anand already answered how to see the custom pages details using Coreservice API.

As @Anand/Peter already mentioned in his comment to clarify how to get the custom page XML using API, because in database it's store as Encoded XML Fragment.

It looks like you are still looking at the database level to see that data not using Coreservice API.

SDL highly recommends that you use the APIs to read. Accessing the database directly carries a high risk. The risk is that you corrupt the database or incur data loss. Only Engineering knows database design and business logic about the database data how it's stored.

Anyway, let me give you two examples one with full Coreservice example another one with database read.

**Coreservice Example:**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Xml;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;

namespace SDL.FindAndReadCustomPagesURL
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ServiceUrl = "{0}webservices/CoreService201603.svc/basicHttp";
        private const int MaxMessageSize = 10485760;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                    var client = GetClient("localhost:7086");

                    client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

                    var appData = client.ReadApplicationData(null, "CustomPages");
                    if (appData != null)
                    {
                        var ada = new ApplicationDataAdapter(appData);

                        XmlElement appDataXml = ada.GetAs<XmlElement>();
                        Console.WriteLine(appDataXml.OuterXml);
                    }  
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write($"Failed to process {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        static CoreServiceClient GetClient(string hostname)
        {
            var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxMessageSize,
                ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = MaxMessageSize,
                    MaxArrayLength = MaxMessageSize
                },
                Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
                {
                    Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
                    Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity
                    {
                        ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows
                    }
                }
            };

            hostname = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", hostname.StartsWith("http") ? "" : "http://", hostname, hostname.EndsWith("/") ? "" : "/");

            var remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress(string.Format(ServiceUrl, hostname));
            return new CoreServiceClient(basicHttpBinding, remoteAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

**Database Level Read:**

```
Use Tridion_cm
SELECT [APP_ID],CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(max),[DATA_CONTENT])) as XMLDATA  
  FROM [Tridion_cm].[dbo].[APP_DATA] WHERE APP_ID='CustomPages'
```

I hope it's helps

Answer (score 7):

it does get stored on DB from SDL 8.6. you can find the details [APP_DATA] table CM Database.

You can use the following code to read the value using core service:

```
var client = CMSession.GetInstance().CoreServiceClient;
var appData = client.ReadApplicationData(null, APPDATA_CUSTOMPAGES_ID);
if (appData != null)
{
    var ada = new ApplicationDataAdapter(appData);
    var appDataXml = ada.GetAs<XmlElement>();
    return appDataXml.OuterXml;
}
```

Comment: Hi Anand, what is APPDATA_CUSTOMPAGES_ID exactly? Is that a constant you defined yourself? If so, what should the value be?

Comment: Yes , it's the ID to get the data_content, if you see on ID field on APP_DATA Table.

Comment: Hi @AnandNS, All the Custom Pages will be resided in Single entry in the Database?. We have found only one record with below details in APP_DATA Table.                                                                                                                     ID:XXXX, APP_ID:  CustomPages, SUBJECT_TYPE:0, SUBJECT_REFERENCE_ID:NULL, 
SUBJECT_PUBLICATION_ID:NULL, SUBJECT_VERSION:NULL,       DATA_TYPE: CustomPages, http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0 DATA_CONTENT: Encrypted Format Content (Binary Data).  We haven't found much information in the table. Any Comments.

Comment: @Sree you need to use core service code provided to read the Encrypted Format Content by passing the ID field , for example , if you have many custom pages you will find the  details the output.

Comment: There is indeed a single entry and it's an XML fragment. Use the ApplicationDataAdapter to read it if you need to. There is no reason why it should be resetting, unless your upload of data includes APP_DATA.

Comment: Hi All, we are facing this problem for our client and Sree G is helping us to find where exactly the issue is. We have an issue that PROD custom page URL gets reset and point it to the DEV custom page URL. So I think reading the values may not help us. We are trying to find where exactly the information is stored and where it picks up from, so that we can try to find why that source is resetting OR is there any regular restores/routines setup erroneously which is messing up with this data. Any help is much appreciated !!

Comment: @SarangDeshmukh , As mentioned the custom pages are stored in DB and when you say that the PROD custom URL gets reset , can you please provide more details on what you do for example did you restore the DB etc. Assume if you login to production and click on the custom page its should point to respective URL specific to the environments. So after you login to CMS Under Custom Page select custom page properties and it should display the Name and URL. Unless you have written any custom code there is no way DEV Custom pages values show up on PROD.

Comment: @AnandNS, exactly my point and that's where we are seeking help from SDL cloud team and 'Sree G', they are helping us to find out where this information is stored in the DB so that we can figure out if there is any DB restore happening which is overwriting it again & again. Also the purpose of this post to understand which DB exactly hold these values so that team can find out if there is any routine setup on the DB restore which is picking up the wring information always. Interestingly when overwrite happens, the modified date-timestamp on custom page properties shows the past date :-)

Comment: @SarangDeshmukh: It's stored in CM database eg (Tridion_cm), quick question is there any content porting export/import done during the time between DEV and PROD?

Comment: @Velmurugan thank you for the inputs. Normally we don't port between DEV & PROD. We port between DEV-TEST or TEST-PROD. To answer your question - 'No' there was no content porting done between DEV & PROD when this happened. Question - in which table from the CM db the custom pages info is stored? Can we see this info in SQL by querying on CM DB?

Comment: @SarangDeshmukh:  It's stored in APP_DATA Table

Comment: @Velmurugan, thanks ! Any query that you can provide to fetch the custom page info? Would be really great help. We did try to check this table with Sree G's help but no luck.

Comment: @SarangDeshmukh: Please see my answer below